# Template in Visual Studio 2019 for Autocad

Tags: c#, templates, autocad-plugin

I want to have a template in visual studio 2019 for Autocad 2017.

My goal is to create a C# ProjectTemplate for AutoCAD in Visual Studio 2019,
template allowing to automatically launch AutoCAD by loading the DLL from Visual Studio in Debug mode.

I followed the instructions below

http://gilecad.azurewebsites.net/Resources/Template_Csharp_EN.pdf

Autocad doesn't load "dll" ,ribbon is missing and its command line is as follows:

> ....
>
> Regenerating model.
>
> AutoCAD menu utilities loaded.*Cancel*
>
> Command: *Cancel*
>
> _RIBBON
>
> Unknown command "RIBBON".  Press F1 for help.
>
> COMMANDLINE
>
> Command:
>
> Command:
>
> Command: netload Assembly file name: "AutoCadPlugin2017.dll"*Cancel*
>
> *Cancel*"AutoCadPlugin2017.dll"
>
> "AutoCadPlugin2017.dll

Answer (score 0):

For me it's not necessarily to use "Add a script to load the application at startup of AutoCAD " at page 4. Just jump to Project-> Export Template. Also you can manage debugging program manually via Properties->Debud->Start external program and browse to Acad.exe. The point is that you my have few versions of Autocad or Civil and you may need to choose specific one for different applications.